# Need sql query for this requirement

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table called ABC and XYZ

Table ABC: I have five columns as Col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5

```
Col_1   col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5
10      20     30     40     50
```

Table XYZ: I have one column as col_Name

```
Col_Name   
col_1  
col_2
col_5
```

I need the output as:

Table Result:

```
col_1  10
col_2  20
col_5  50
```

Comment: That is really hard to do because of this bad table design. Consider changin it.

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: @ramesh:"oracle 10g"

Comment: I agree with juergen d. The database design is bad. In a database you would have entities like employees, jobs, items, orders and the like, not table or column names. The dbms (Oracle in your case) on the other hand administrates tables and columns and has therefore system tables containing these. Don't play dbms, administrate your own data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
     Col_name,
     CASE WHEN Col_Name = 'col_1' THEN TableABC.col_1
          WHEN Col_Name = 'col_2' THEN TableABC.col_2
          WHEN Col_Name = 'col_3' THEN TableABC.col_3
          WHEN Col_Name = 'col_4' THEN TableABC.col_4
          WHEN Col_Name = 'col_5' THEN TableABC.col_5
     END AS Result
FROM TableXYZ, TableABC
```

There's not a dynamic way in most database systems to choose columns.

Comment: @ramesh: "ABC is a configuration table columns may increase it should be dynamic"

Comment: @ramesh:"I need only col_1, col_2,col_5 because i have only these columns in table XYZ"